# Unexpected behavior using jQuery.extend with custom objects as attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery (1.11.2) and $.extend to clone an object. This doesn't work as expected.

I have a source object containing two attributes with custom instances of functions (new function...) as values. These values seems to be copied as references where I expect them to be copied as values. See the code below.

```
var AnyObj = function(){
  this.attribute = "anyAttribute";
};

var target = {
  a: new AnyObj(),
  b: new AnyObj()
}
//this prints "anyAttribute"
console.log(target.a)
//now I create a deep copy
var copy = $.extend(true, {},target);
//and I change the attribute of the COPY(!!!)
copy.a.attribute = "YAYA";
//this prints an object with  the value YAYA
console.log(copy.a)
//this should NOT print  an object with  the value YAYA
console.log(target.a)
```

Comment: ^^
if I use {a:{attribute:'v'}} instead of {a: new AnyObj()} it works.

Comment: As you're passing an object which contains 2 more object `(a and b)`, so whenever you change that object it will update actual object only, if you want to see that difference then try `var copy = $.extend(true, {},target.a);` passing just an object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a jQuery extend() bug. Refer to below for more details:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10014